# errors for simple Labels in java

Tags: java, netbeans, label

i just upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04 and i'm trying to make  a simple Labels app as a practice however i faced weird error complains from the Java interpreter.
 I'm kinda sure the code is fine because it's fairly simple that's why i can't figure out the problem if someone can help me with this and thanks:

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package guis;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author ophiel
 */
public class Labeling extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage s){
        HBox box = new HBox();
        ImageView im = new ImageView(new Image("images/lock.png"));
        Label lab = new Label("lock\n24 Stages",im);
        lab.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.BOTTOM);
        lab.setStyle("-fx-border:green;-fx-stroke:black;");
        Label lab1 = new Label("Circle",new Circle(50,50,50));
        lab1.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.CENTER);

        Label lab2 = new Label("Rectangle",new Rectangle(10,10,40,50));
        lab2.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.LEFT);
        box.getChildren().addAll(lab,lab1,lab2);
        s.setScene(new Scene(box,200,200));
        s.show();


    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Application.launch(args);
    }

}
```

and this is the interpreter's messages :

```
 run:
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1100)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:608)
    at guis.Labeling.start(Labeling.java:27)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$50(GtkApplication.java:139)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1092)
    ... 11 more
Exception running application guis.Labeling
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 11 seconds)
```

i'm running ubuntu 15.04 desktop version my IDE is netBeans 8.0.2 and java version "1.8.0_60"

Comment: problem solved it appear to be  an ide bug related , i rebooted netbeans and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't find the image file:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1092)
```

Comment: i commented the label that contain the image and took it off from box.getchildren i still got the same error messages, i even used a link from the web it doesn't seem like it's getting fixed